# To select a list of record satisfying multiple AND condition

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have two tables with the fields as below

```
______________
|Game_Details:|
|_____________|______
|Game_Id | Game_Name|
__________
|WC_Info:|
|________|_____________________________
|S/N | Game_Id | Country_Name| WC_Won|
```

I am trying to fetch the list of game_name which are being played in atleast the 4 countries (India, England,France, Italy) and the field WC_Won is 0 for all of them.

The below query is fetching incorrect details.can someone please suggest the way to get it.

```
Select G.Game_Name
From Game_Details G
Inner Join WC_Info W
    On G.Game_Id=W.Game_Id
Where W.WC_Won=0
Group By Game_Name
Having Count(Country_Name in (India, England,France, Italy))>3
```

Comment: Try use quotes in the country names ->     Having Count(Country_Name in ('India', 'England','France', 'Italy'))>3

Comment: mysql or oracle? Not the same thing, although the SQL _might_ be the same depending on circumstances. Just tag the DBMS you're actually using.

Comment: Tag properly!!!  MySQL <> Oracle!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this select statement :

```
Select distinct G.Game_Name 
  From Game_Details G
 Where G.Game_Id in ( Select Game_Id 
           From WC_Info W 
          Where W.WC_Won=0 
            And Country_Name in ('India', 'England','France', 'Italy') 
          Group By Game_Id 
         Having Count( distinct Country_Name ) = 4 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close:

```
Select G.Game_Name
From Game_Details G Inner Join
     WC_Info W
     On G.Game_Id = W.Game_Id 
Where W.WC_Won = 0
Group By Game_Name
Having Count(distinct case when Country_Name in ('India', 'England', 'France', 'Italy')
                           then country_name
             end) = 4;
```

I find the use of an inequality to be misleading.  You want all four countries, so `= 4` makes more sense than `> 3` or `>= 4`.

Alternatively, you can filter on the country *before* the aggregation:

```
Select G.Game_Name
From Game_Details G Inner Join
     WC_Info W
     On G.Game_Id = W.Game_Id 
Where W.WC_Won = 0 and
      Country_Name in ('India', 'England', 'France', 'Italy')
Group By Game_Name
Having Count(distinct country_name) = 4;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon for making me understand this